# How to split input form and send to Mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysqli

I have a form which works well when calling to server

I want it to work when a person sends more than one input code

how do I set it to work with textarea instead short input

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="" method="POST">
  <input class="input" name="search" id="search" value="" size="13" maxlength="13" dir="ltr" autocomplete="on" type="text" width="150" height="20" onchange="document.getElementById('yq_num').value = this.value;"> 
  <input value="חפש" name="button" alt="submit" onclick="showDiv();" border="0" type="button" align="absmiddle">
</form>

<div id="hiddenDiv" class="answer_list"></div>


NEW FORM 
<form action="" method="POST">
<textarea name="search" rows="4" cols="50" id="search"> </textarea>
<input value="search" name="button" alt="submit" onclick="showDiv();" border="0" type="button" align="absmiddle">
</form>
```

example user writes, RR123456789IL, RR123456789US, RR123456789UK

javascript code ,
takes the input form and return with jquery the result into hidden Div

```
document.getElementById('quickContactForm')
$(document).ready(function(){
//$("#hiddenDiv").hide();
});

function showDiv(){
  var str=$("#search").val();
  var url="action.php?show="+str;
  console.log('url'+url);
  $.get(url,function(data,status){
  //   alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      $("#hiddenDiv").html(data);
      $("#hiddenDiv").show();
  });

   document.getElementById('signup').style.display = 'block';
}
```

action.php
recieve user's code and return its result from server

```
<?php

//$itemCode = "RR123456789IL";
$itemCode = $_GET["show"];
 $itemType = substr( $itemCode, 0, 2 ) . substr( $itemCode, -2 );

$url = "http://www.israelpost.co.il/itemtrace.nsf/trackandtraceJSON?openagent&_=1412972965324&lang=HE&itemcode={$itemCode}&sKod2={$itemType}";

$json = file_get_contents($url);

$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->{'itemcodeinfo'}; // 12345

require_once('logger.php');

?>
```

logger.php -> store data in Mysql database.

what I want is to change the form to textarea, and send multiple POST codes seperated with commas or space, each code is 13 digits
and return multiple answers to html 
and store in DB each code in a new row.
Thanks

The database Insert code (Updated)
logger.php

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$IP = "$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO enterlog (ItemCode, EnterDate, IPAddress, Info) VALUES ('$itemCode', '$time', '$IP', '$obj')";


if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: And you need to know how to make a textarea? <textarea name=''></textarea>

Comment: This I know, mean how to seperate the textarea codes

Comment: What do you mean with textarea codes? Show an example?

Comment: Okay I'm adding to the post under form

Comment: Do you want to know how to get the values from the textarea? Or something else? It's still not clear to me :\

Comment: @JeroenBellemans Yes I have added examples, change the input line to text area. my question involves many things

Answer (score 1):

What I'm guessing is that you need `explode` function inside your `logger.php`.

```
$string = $_POST['value']; // Your codes, separated by a comma
$strings = explode(",", $string);

foreach ($strings as $string) {

    echo $string; // This should be each code you want

}
```

Sending the data to the database is very simple and should be done inside the `foreach` loop, as you want a new row for each code.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `table_name` (`code`) VALUES ('" . $string . "')";
$con->query($query);
```

This is far as I go. You are compiling several questions in one...

Comment: Thanks man. but this prints the codes the user puts, what about sending them to server, and returnning results, and update the database

Comment: I updated the answer, but your question is way to broad.

Comment: Okay, I attach a working example of similiar code with textarea [link](http://glgltzla.com/mail/)

Comment: I still don't get your problem. What do you want the textarea does?

Comment: I tried your help, as you said my question is a bit long, I should split it to 3 parts. 1st part is to check codes seperated with commas, tried the explode didn't work, i get only the first code result, not the rest i put

Comment: Did you change the `$_POST['value']` to `$_GET['show']` ?

Comment: Yep, I changed it , for some reason the loop works and I get multiple results, BUT it works only locally... and not on site. and as well can't put them on DB..... what could it  be?

Comment: I have checked they're correct, it managed to post the first item

Comment: Can you share the code where you post the values to the database?

Comment: I've added the code. next issue I want to take $obj from action.php and update the mysql with the result, what can be the reason. the $obj comes from a json